# What does a bouncing Training Error mean in an LSTM?

Tags: lstm, tensorflow, training-error

I have an Bidirectional LSTM of size 1024, running over a sequences of variable length. My dataset is 100,000 items large, with a 256 batch size. I'm taking the last relevant step, concatenating forward and backward passes, then sending out the results to a fully connected layer.

I've noticed some kind of bouncing that grows bigger the further the training descends. I don't know what this means. I suspect this is happening at the beginning or end of each epoch. In this image I'm around epoch 28.

[image: bouncing training error]

It seems to be getting worse which is very odd. I'm using the RMSProp optimizer with 0.006 learning rate.

Has anyone seen this sort of thing before?

Cheers
B

UPDATE!

This seems to be even more pronounced when using the AdamOptimizer. 
Im applying a small l1_regulariser to the weights of the final output layer. Clearly, the sawtooth look is getting worse

[image: adam version]

Comment: Is your learning rate decaying?

Comment: Im using tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer which I believe has a 0.9 decay by default.

Comment: The “bounces” look really similar. My guess is that it’s overfitting and bouncing because of outliers;. found some minima, but some data points are outliers and pushes it up, and then it goes pack down when others data comes. Repeats in epochs?

Comment: I think you might be right, given a few related issues. Overfitting and memorising does seem likely. Thanks.